# Public exposure/indecency: how do porno companies get away with it?

Tags: corporate-law, jurisdiction

I hate to ask, but with all the disgusting porn out there how is it legal that some is filmed in public? For example, in Eastern countries such as Hungary do they not have indecent exposure/public nudity/obscenity laws? I think I've even seen some videos on video sharing websites where they are in the US and a women is engaging in sex acts on the street. How isn't this illegal?

Comment: Closed sets with limited access with permits to film from the local government and extras paid to replace the people in the background

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough to comment, but there are some large porno companies that do this on a regular basis and get away with this. One of their disclaimers states

> All sexual activities and acts of public sex depicted on example.com
>   are fully legal and have been filmed in full compliance with the laws
>   of the material's respective country of production

This question has been raised on other sites

https://www.quora.com/How-legal-and-ethical-is-the-public-stuff-of-those-Princess-Donna-Public-Disgrace-videos
http://charlieglickman.com/2011/03/20/consent-and-public-disgrace/

Comment: It might be worthwhile to point out that the disclaimer is probably not correct if it is attached to a video of people having sex in public.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably illegal, just not pursued. In the case of something like bank robbery, you'd have a victim that filed a police report. A murder would need to be discovered somehow - either a missing person report or a dead body. If the porn shoot happened somewhere that a member of the public saw it and subsequently filed a police report, the video could be used as evidence. Absent a report, the police simply have no reason to look into it (unless the police catches them in the act, but we probably don't see those videos posted online).

Why would these public offenses go unreported? Perhaps nobody sees it. Perhaps the bystanders in the video are paid extras. Maybe they're filming in what appears to be public but is actually private property. Perhaps they have a permit to use a public space for this purpose. Perhaps they just got lucky. Again, there might be some confirmation bias here - you're not going to see as many videos of folks they catch breaking the law, since they will either be interrupted and stopped or (maybe) have their videos ordered taken down.

Answer (score -1):

It is illegal but, just like bank robbery, it happens.

Comment: Yep, just because someone gets away with it doesn't mean it is legal. Piracy is another that happens a lot.

Comment: @Terry, Dale: but bank robbers who sell video of themselves in action will most likely find themselves facing prosecution.  They won't "get away with it."  Why is pornography different?

Comment: @phoog Combination of who's going to report it ("_I'm happy watching porn, but how **dare** they film it in public?_") and how bothered police are going to bothered chasing a victimless/no loss crime after the event.

Comment: @phoog I was using it as an example that crime goes on regardless.

Answer (score -1):

i know that in hungary there exist no law for filming in public, not even porn.
in the past they even rent faemous public buildings for pornshot, like castles and library and schools.
they even shoot porn in traffic on a public bus

Comment: Citations needed.